# Strange font issues on Ubuntu 14.04 Unity

Tags: 14.04, unity, fonts, gtk

somehow the fonts on my ubuntu machine started looking really strange:

[image]

I tried reinstalling the unity light theme, but that didn't change anything unfortunately.
Do you have an idea how to fix this issue?

Comment: What are your font hinting and sub-pixel font anti-aliasing settings? You can look them up in [Ubuntu Tweak](https://launchpad.net/~tualatrix/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) under Tweaks → Fonts in the lower section ([screenshot](//i.imgur.com/fXwRKMj.png)). Try to change the settings and see, if that helps. Sometimes the configuration files get messed up and resetting them brings them back to a sane state.

Comment: FWIW : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/1501421

Comment: I encountered the same problem all of a sudden and I managed to resolve it by simply a `apt-get update` and an `apt-get upgrade`. I suspect that either some buggy package update messed up with my fonts or (more possibly) some upgrade was interrupted. In any case, I would suggest that before you try anything more intricate, try an update/upgrade.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'v got the same issue too! It seems to me that started to happen after i did a new install of last firefox directly from mozilla.org (not from official canonical repos). I checked out the [requirements](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/33.1.1/system-requirements/) and i installed among others the 'Pango' package.

Shortly in my case the issue has been resolved by uninstalling those packages:

- pango-graphite
- gsfonts-X11
- libgraphite3

Hope it helps.

Comment: FWIW, I have a similar issue and these packages are not installed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to download & configure [unity-tweak-tool](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/unity-tweak-tool/). And try to change the font. I think after that your problem is solved.

OR

Recent updates in my system have been changing the font scaling factors, reset them with this command.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor '1.0'
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't help. I checked with a second Ubuntu systems and the font-Settings are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

1- open your terminal. 2- Right click inside your terminal window from the menu hover over profiles then from the sub-menu click profile preference. 3- You should see a window with many tabs be sure that General tab is active. 4 Unchick the option "Use the system fixed width font".

hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately this does not help. In addtion I'm not exclusively facing these issues in the terminal application. Also the window titles look strange and the font in eclipse is also different from the default.

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem appears when Terminal is open for a long time and is not being used.
Fix:
Right Click inside Terminal -> Profile -> Preference -> General Tab -> Check Custom Font -> Set Font to Monospace 10pt.

This is how I fixed mine.